# On the Sylow $2$-subgroup of a nonabelian simple group.

Tags: finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite nonabelian simple group and $P$ be a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$.

QUESTION:

Is $P$ cyclic or quaternion group?

Answer (score 2):

The thesis [On Sylow $2$-subgroups of finite simple groups of order up to $2^{10}$](https://etd.ohiolink.edu/rws_etd/document/get/osu1086112148/inline) gives a list of groups which are realizable as Sylow $2$-subgroups of $G$. So we see that there are many possibilities. So $P$ need neither be cyclic nor quaternion. In fact, $Q_8$ is not realizable.
Indeed, certain groups are never realizable, e.g., all abelian 2-groups with an automorphism group that is a 2-group.are not realizable.

Actually, very good answers have been given at this "duplicate":

[What do Sylow 2-subgroups of finite simple groups look like?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785603/what-do-sylow-2-subgroups-of-finite-simple-groups-look-like)

Comment: Isn't "abelian 2-groups with an automorphism group that is a 2-group" the same as a cyclic $2$-group?